# Tipo de retorno variável

Tags: c++, funções, genéricos, vector

Eu quero fazer funções com tipo de entrada variante, como isso:

```
int count(vector<auto> base, auto val)
{
    int sum= 0;

    for (auto it : base)
    {
        if (it == val)
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

ou isso:

```
string str(auto a)
{
    stringstream x;
    x << a;
    return x.str();
}
```

Mas como é claro, não funcionou. Recebi o seguinte erro:

```
error: invalid use of 'auto'
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Precisa explicar melhor o que deseja, tem cara que está querendo usar um *template*, mas a pergunta não diz nada.

Comment: eu não faço ideia do que é um _template_

Comment: Então explique o que quer fazer pra gente poder te ajudar..

Comment: @bigown, percebi como minha pergunta era idiota. Post atualizado.

Comment: @FelipeNascimento existem perguntas idiotas, e existem perguntas como essa aí. Pode ser trivial para quem o conhecimento, mas para quem está se iniciando no campo, até o mais trivial pode ser novidade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que deseja usar um [gabarito de função](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
vector<T> filter(vector<T> base, T val) {
    vector<T> temp;
    for (auto it : base) if (it == val) temp.push_back(it);
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {7, 5, 16, 8, 5, 12, 1};
    for (auto it : filter(v, 5)) cout << it << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Agg9V2).  E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kswcnanb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/FilterValue.cpp).

Note que existem algoritmos genéricos prontos no C++ para fazer isto, por exemplo [`copy_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) ou o [`remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Não é a mesma coisa, mas podem ser mais úteis.