# C++: Erro com Gabarito de Função

Tags: c++, header

Eu criei uma função usando gabarito, conforme demonstrado [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215352/c-tipo-de-retorno-vari%C3%A1vel), desta forma:

utilits.h

```
...
template<typename T> bool theres(T a, vector<T> b); 
...
```

utilits.cpp

```
...
template<typename T> bool theres(T a, vector<T> b)
{
    for(T& it : b)
        if (it == a)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
...
```

main.cpp

```
...
vector<string> registro(0);
...
int main ()
{
    ...
    string nick = "far";
    ...
    if(theres(nick, registro)) // <- Erro aqui
    ...
}
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

```
undefined reference to `bool theres<std::string>(std::string, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >)'
```

Comment: Essa minha informação pode estar datada, mas C++ lida com templates via substituição de código. Isso significa que o código gabaritado precisa estar na mesma unidade de compilação do código em que se coloca o tipo no gabarito; ou seja, implementação no `.h`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, valeu cara, está funcionando. Eu não sabia que podia implementar a variável no arquivo `.h`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, por que você respondeu com um comentário em vez de uma resposta?

Comment: @KyleA achei que não tinha qualidade suficiente para resposta. Curto e sem explicação

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que quando se chama uma função que usa o template, ela é replicada com as características passadas. Por exemplo, nesta mina função:

```
template<typename T> bool theres(T a, vector<T> b);
```

Quando chamo ela conforme a pergunta, o compilador identifica `T` como sendo `string`, então cria no arquivo de cabeçalho a função:

```
bool theres(string a, vector<string> b);
```

Porém, ao tentar fazer o link com o arquivo `.cpp`, não encontra a implementação da função `theres(string, vector<string>)`, gerando o erro.
A solução então colocar a implementação no arquivo `.h`, junto da declaração, fazendo assim:

utilits.h

```
...
template<typename T> bool theres(T a, vector<T> b)
{
    for(T& it : b)
        if (it == a)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
...
```

main.cpp

```
...
vector<string> registro(0);
...
int main ()
{
    ...
    string nick = "far";
    ...
    if(theres(nick, registro))
    ...
}
```

Eu espero ter ajudado alguém que tenha o mesmo problema.